# Monitoring circuit for the switching voltage

Tags: power-supply, voltage, switching, voltage-monitor, supervisor

I would like to monitor the switching voltage which is switching between 24V and ground at a frequency of 100kHz. If the voltage is below 21V, then generate a reset signal. The lines are the differential lines with a different ground than the monitoring circuit. Some more info: the lines are the outputs of the half bridge circuit.

For example, using this [device.](https://datasheet.octopart.com/MCP120T-475I/TT-Microchip-datasheet-345.pdf)

Comment: In what way do you wish to supervise the 100 kHz 24 volt waveform?

Comment: I would generate a reset if the 24V level is less than 21V. Let me say I use MCP120T-475I/TT for this function.

Comment: You need to provide more detail about what you want to do. You state a frequency so there is a waveform..

Comment: @Durgaprasad That doesn't sound like "supervision" to me. That sounds like you want to make a new signal that has a go/no-go status? In other words you want to monitor rather than supervise. If you feel the chip you mention is relevant then create a hyperlink to the data sheet.

Comment: Its square waveform switching between 24v and 0V

Comment: @Andy, Yes you are right. I want to monitor this signal and generate reset in case if it is less than 21V.

Comment: Then be clear what you want and amend your original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest and probably the most fool-proof method is to use a capacitively coupled isolating pulse transformer. This then allows you to take the isolated differential signal and reference it to your monitor circuit ground. In other words, the pulse transformer provides the galvanic barrier you might need and it also delivers a single ended signal that can be monitored by a voltage comparator circuit.

If you didn't require galvanic isolation, you can still use a transformer as per above or, you can use a differential amplifier made from an op-amp and four resistors.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122543/discussion-on-answer-by-andy-aka-monitoring-circuit-for-the-switching-voltage).